# Check value at insert

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

i have this three tables.

```
Table: Item
Columns: ItemID, Title, Content, NoChange (Date)

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: ItemTag
Columns: ItemID, TagID
```

In the Item Table is a Field with NoChange, if this field = true no Tag is allowed to insert a ItemTag value with this ItemID. How can i check this in the insert?

For Updates i have this Statement:

```
UPDATE ItemTag SET TagID = ? where ItemID = ? 
AND TagID = ? AND exists (
select ItemID from Item where ItemID = ? AND NoChange is null)");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query-Syntax of the insert statement:

INSERT INTO ItemTag (TagID,ItemID) SELECT ?,? FROM item where itemid=? and nochange is null

where the first parameter is your tagid and the 2nd and 3rd your itemid.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement [does not accept conditions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ AS output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

What you could do is add a trigger to check if the conditions have been met and either rollback the transaction or skip the insert ([the trigger should return null](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/trigger-definition.html)).

You could also write a relatively simple plpgsql procedure (which would be my choice if I was really bent on performing this check at the database level).